# md5deep doesn't output in a consistent order

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, md5

I recently discovered md5deep (https://github.com/jessek/hashdeep).  I am using it with my macOS terminal to create a list of the files on my internal hard drive, and a list of the files on my external backup hard drive.  I am then using Excel to compare the two and make sure there are no differences.

The output order is usually alphabetical, but it's sometimes not, which messes up the Excel calculation since it is inconsistent.

Here's an example:

> MSK/Dissection Guides/Day 1 Dissection guide (Hip) - MSK 2018.pdf
>   MSK/Dissection Guides/Day 2 Dissection Guide (Ankle) - MSK 2018.pdf
>   MSK/Dissection Guides/Day 1 Dissection guide - MSK 2018JMEditsMay12ACCEPT-1.docx
>   MSK/Dissection Guides/Day 3 Dissection Guide (Knee) - MSK 2018.pdf
>   MSK/Dissection Guides/Day 2 Dissection guide - MSK 2018JMEditsMay12ACCEPT.docx
>   MSK/Dissection Guides/Day 5 Dissection Guide (Elbow) - MSK 2018.pdf
>   MSK/Dissection Guides/Day 3 Dissection guide - MSK 2018JMEditsMay12ACCEPT.docx
>   MSK/Dissection Guides/Day 6 Dissection Guide (Wrist) - MSK 2018.pdf
>   MSK/Dissection Guides/Day 5 Dissection Guide (elbow)JMEditsMay192018ACCEPT.docx
>   MSK/Dissection Guides/Day 6 Dissection Guide (wrist)JMEditsMay192018ACCEPT.docx

Why is it usually alphabetical (but not every 50-100 files or so), and what can I do to make the list of both copies in an identical order so that their m5d's can be compared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort your files prior to comparing them (you can compare them with `diff`):

```
sort <md5_file1> > sorted_md5_file1
sort <md5_file2> > sorted_md5_file2
diff sorted_md5_file1 sorted_md5_file2
```